Web3.js returning out-of-gas on local node with high --rpc.gascap
I have a local Fantom API node (lachesis) that I start with a really high --rpc.gascap (over 5 billion), which should not be hit in theory. However, when I make an eth_call using Web3.js, it always reverts with an out-of-gas error. In my testing attempts, I discovered that the max execution gas of an eth_call seems to be 50 million (I assume this is the block gas limit).
What am I missing here? I am running a local node with the intent to make large batch calls. I have read that changing the genesis file might help, but I haven't played with that yet as I am connected to the Fantom mainnet and do not know the full consequences or whether it is needed in the first place.
